# Error storing a date in an object using workday function

Tags: vba, excel, date, object

I have the following simple code:

```
    Sub newsub()

Dim currentday As Date
Dim cd As String

currentday = Format(WorskheetFunction.WorkDay(today, -1), dd / mm / aaaa)
cd = currentday
MsgBox cd

End Sub
```

But I get

> 424 ERROR: AN OBJECT IS REQUIRED

Anyone could tell me why is this happening?

Comment: `Worskheet`...?

Comment: Use `Now` instead of `today`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> WorskheetFunction.WorkDay
> ```

You have a typo here, VBA runtime doensn't know what to resolve `WorkskheetFunction` to, and **because Option Explicit isn't specified**, it's creating an undeclared variable on-the-fly, an implicit `Variant` whose underlying type depends on how and where you're using it.

And because `ABC.XYZ(foo, bar)` can only grammatically be a member call on some object, VBA runtime expects `WorkskheetFunction` to be an object, and it isn't - it's never assigned, so its underlying type is `Variant/Empty`, which isn't an object - hence, an "Object Required" error is thrown.

#### Always use Option Explicit.

Then you won't be happily compiling and running code with typos.

You could also leverage IntelliSense to help prevent typos, by qualifying `WorksheetFunction` with the global `Application` object:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(...)
```

That way you get autocomplete/IntelliSense when you type the `.` dot. Another difference is that if the worksheet function throws an error, with this early-bound syntax you'll get an actual VBA runtime error, whereas with the late-bound syntax you're using (with which you're not getting parameter tooltips / intellisense) if the function results in an error value it will *return* an error and make an invalid assignment to a `Date` variable, throwing a potentially confusing "Type Mismatch" error.

Answer (score 1):

You need quotes around `"dd/mm/aaa"` (which I think should actually be `"dd/mm/yyyy"`)

You also may want to use this instead since `Format` returns a string, not a date:

```
currentday = CVDate(Format(WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Now(), -1), "dd/mm/yyyy"))
```

Comment: It worked too, thanks. so, CVDate returns a date object and format a string?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be trying to format Today, I would replace that with Now() and it works as expected.

Change your code to the following:

```
Sub newsub()
Dim currentday As Date
currentday = Format(Now() - 1, "dd/mm/yyyy") 'use Now() and format to your liking to get the right date
MsgBox currentday 
End Sub
```

Comment: It worked, thanks, could you tell me why I have to use variant format in this case?

Comment: Depending on whether you need the time it may be better to use `Date()` rather than `Now()`.  E.g. `Now()` will return `13/12/2017 16:00:33` while `Date` returns `13/12/2017`  The formatting may differ depending on locale and I'm not sure of the difference between `Now` and `Now()` - both return the same and `Vartype()` says they're both date variable types.